# Speed of mysql update / set statement. Multiplying a column

Tags: mysql, performance

I have 1 million rows in MySql table "temp" and wish to multiply column "t" (int unsigned, indexed) by 1000.

```
mysql> update temp set t=1000*t;
```

This process takes 25 seconds. The same statement on not-indexed column takes 10 seconds;

Any ideas how to make this process faster? I have to apply this on over 1e5 tables.

Comment: I'd say having 10,000 tables with a million rows each is the source of your problem. What in the world are you doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing has nothing to do with the problem here. Think about what you're doing - you're mutating all the rows in your table, so no matter how you select them and if you have an index on t or not, you're still scanning the whole table.

The UPDATE operation == IO is what your bottleneck is. Get faster disks.

If you're using InnoDB, my only advice would be to see if tweaking [innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit) and setting it to 2 helps your performance but I doubt it as it's just 1 query. Disabling keys and re-enabling them after UPDATE won't work in InnoDB.

Comment: exactly, any type of change on that many rows would do the same thing. Even if your adding or removing a column on the table. +1

Comment: He says the query runs over twice as fast with indexing off.  Explain that

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed the part where it was different. I will rethink my advice.

Comment: Thanks, 
The ironic point here is that recreating this table  ( creating a table with index, loading from a text file all 5 columns ) takes 11 seconds. That is why I search for a faster solution.

Comment: Sergey, what is the table type?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn indexing off and back on after the updates are done

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENABLE KEYS;
```

Or if you are using myISAM
You can use the delay_key_write flag.  You can set it per-table, or
globally.  You can use the "FLUSH TABLE mytable" command to force mysql
to update the on-disk copy of the indexes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/create-table.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/myisam-start.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/flush.html

Comment: Heikki himself mentioned it doens't affect InnoDB http://www.mail-archive.com/mysql@lists.mysql.com/msg64348.html but it was in 2003 and he may have been smoking crack and thinking the question applied to unique keys only.

Comment: Confirmed as not working in InnoDB by http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=5187 and me just trying it and viewing warnings.

Comment: OP confirmed that table type is InnoDB. This solution, though good for MyISAM, won't work in his case.